# Why not redeclare DataContext property in WPF, if calling base

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns

In a code behind XAML file, if my DataContext will always be a well-known class, i usually redeclare DataContext like this:

```
public new Cow DataContext
{
    get { return base.DataContext as Cow; }
    set { base.DataContext = value; }
}
```

This way i have Intellisense treating DataContext as a Cow in the scope of my file and I am safely (at least i think so) using the **base.DataContext to handle all its logic**.

Some people, with lots of experience, have already told me that this is not a good pattern.

I'd like to know what problems could arise and why not use it. I've already given it a lot of thought and couldn't think of one

Thank you

Comment: I assume you redeclare DataContext in your .xaml.cs file (code behind)  since you said in your "xaml" but posted c# code ?

Comment: @scott i am really sorry but i meant property named DataContext instead of Cow

Comment: @Luis Filipe, I just saw your updated change and deleted my comment. I understand what you mean now.

Comment: seems to work with the binding and stuff, but I'd like the intellisense to be narrowed to the viewmodel, rather than all properties of the view + datacontext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After pondering for a while about that code I cannot find any serious issue, except perhaps for this corner case that I will explain.

Let's say your Xaml belongs to a class called MyUserControl, and that it inherits from UserControl.

Let's assume you have:

```
UserControl ctrl = new MyUserControl();
ctrl.DataContext = new Dog();
```

This is obviously legal and you are not protected by MyUserControl's type-safety, because the type of the reference variable is of UserControl, whose DataContext property is still of object type. However, let's immagine down the line, you try the following, in MyUserControl's context:

```
Cow c = this.DataContext;
```

c will be null. This is what you intended. However, it might make your life harder under a debugging scenario because you are being lulled into thinking your DataContext is null, while it simply isn't what you expected it to be. It might be harder to understand why your data bindings are all working funny while your datacontext seems to be null.

My approach to this is not to hide the DataContext property, but to re-expose it via a new property:

```
public Cow Model
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataContext as Cow;
    }
    set
    {
        this.DataContext = value;
    }
}
```

In the scenario I set up above, while the Model property would return null, the DataContext would return a reference to the Dog instance, more appropriately reflecting what is really going on. Alternatively, you might implement your DataContext property's getter by returning the following:

```
return (Cow)this.DataContext;
```

At least you'd receive an exception telling you DataContext does have something, but not what you want. It does seem cheesy, however.

Anyhow, this is really no serious issue, only a possible inconvenience under the scenario I laid out.

Comment: The exception would be a StackOverflowException :). But I guess you meant (Cow)base.DataContext

Comment: @Rui Exposing DataContext via a new property has been my solution ever since i was not allowed to redeclare DataContext;

Comment: @Rui To softly cast DataContext using the keyword 'as' can have the disadvantage you talk about but hard casting it can provoke some unnecessary exceptions to be thrown

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont observe any issues with this and this only helps with IntelliSense... it doesnt change the DataContext dependency property to Cow anyways ... so there is no type safety as far as WPF features like Binding or Styles are concerned.